# Common code for try catch in multiple method in same class of java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

I have java class with more than 100 methods and in each method I have to put try catch code. In each try code  I have different logic. How can I develop common code in Java?

My sample code:

```
public void method1(){

    try {
        int a = 2 +3 ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void method2(){

    try {
        int a = 4 +3 ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void method3(){

    try {
        int a = 2 +6 ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void method4(){

    try {
        int a = 2 +9 ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

There are more than 100+ methods.. and putting try catch in each is hectic.

Kindly advise what I can do.

===========================

My code with consumer::

```
public class ConsumerCheckExceptionWrapper {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T extends Throwable> T hiddenThrowClause(Throwable t) throws T {
    throw (T)t;
}


public static <T extends Throwable> Consumer<T> tryCatchBlock(ConsumerCheckException<T> consumr) throws T {
    System.out.println("tryCatchBlock method");
    return t -> {
        try {
            consumr.accept(t);
        } catch (Throwable exc) {
            ConsumerCheckExceptionWrapper.<RuntimeException> hiddenThrowClause(exc);
            System.out.println("exc :: " + exc.getStackTrace());
        }
    };
}
```

}

```
 @FunctionalInterface 
public interface ConsumerCheckException<T>{
     void accept(T elem) throws Exception; }
```

// -----------------

// call inside my method:

```
ConsumerCheckExceptionWrapper.tryCatchBlock(err ->
mymethod(val1,val2));
```

Comment: sounds like you're stuck doing a lot copy and pasting

Comment: Actually it is refactoring task and make all try catch code snipped as common .

Comment: Catching in all possible places is bad policy. Catch have sense when reaction concrete reaction is possible

Answer (score 1):

You can add throws declaration in all your method and catch the exception where you call the methods. That will make things simpler. Something like this

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    try{
        //call methods here
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }


 public void method1() throws Exception{

    int a = 4+3;


}

public void method2() throws Exception{

    int a = 4 +3 ;


}

public void method3() throws Exception{

    int a = 2 +6 ;

}


public void method4() throws Exception{

    int a = 2 +9 ;


}

}
```

Comment: This look good. But this has a problem for me. I want all my methods to be executed irrespective of the result of previous method. In this case, it will stop executing if error comes in method 1.

Comment: I fear that is not possible. Exceptions are not designed that way. You can only achieve that by what you have written in question That way all methods would be run independently.

The whole point of try catch is to stop execution if try catch occurs or handle it accordingly.

You can use finally block which will execute no matter what exception will occur, but that wont solve your problem either.

Comment: Can I use Consumer and lambda expressions?

Comment: you wont know until you try it. so go for it and let me know if you face problems.

Comment: Its not working with consumers. It is going inside try but now not going inside my method.